# how to use a timer to restart sqldependency if dependency was lost

Tags: c#, sql, sqldependency

I have got my sqldependency working fine. Then someone raised a question saying that, the dependency may lose due to some reasons, such as, datatbase server restart, disconnected.

I got suggested to use a timer, says every half hours to check if sqldependency is lost then we will retart the dependency. And personally I think using a timer seems to be the right way to solve this.

How can I check if the dependency needs to be restarted ?

```
SqlDependency.Stop()   //would give me a Boolean, but at the same time it stop it, which I don't think is quite right.
```

Any suggestion to how to create the timer would be very helpful.

a article about the similar issue is here as well
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/543921/sqldependency-incorrect-behaviour-after-sql-server-restarts

Thanks in advance